# Idiom or expression for no-one wants to help do a task, but everyone is ready to criticise after the task is completed

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or expression that means "no-one wants to help do a task, but everyone is ready to criticise after the task is completed"

There are plenty of expressions that capture the criticising after the task is complete (e.g. hindsight is 20/20), but none that I can think of where the same person/people criticising also had an opportunity to help.

Answer (score 1):

put up or shut up  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Put+Up+or+Shut+Up) an idiom

> To take action or steps to resolve something that one dislikes or else
>   stop complaining about it.

As in:

> 2003 New York Times Iraq's unexpected willingness to grant access to
>   United Nations weapons inspectors presented American intelligence with
>   a challenge to put up or shut up.

Comment: Putting up your rep. +1